# Keeping things in place

Tags: formatting

Hi guys I have a very stupid question. I call it stupid because it's probably something really easy to fix but since I am a noob I can't do it. I tried asking the question on a comment section of another question I posted but somehow he couldn't understand me. So I made a new question with visual aids because visual aids are always easy to understand. Ok so here is the situation.

[image: First Page]

Ok here is the first page. As you can see there is almost half a page of gap here. But I have mentioned that I will be displaying information in the following pages. Btw Grey represents used up space on the page and white represents empty space.

[image: Page 2 with table]

Ok so here are pages 2,3,4. These pages represent tables. They are horizontal tables as in landscape so moving a part of the table to the page before is not an option. I am using the `rotating` package and `sideway` environment for this. Now here is where the problem comes.

[image]

On page 3 I want my results to start as shown in the image. But this entire result section moves up, goes back to the first page, to fit in the box show as "EMPTY BLANK SPACE". Now obviously that is stupid because I have a heading, important tables, then a line and then a new heading talking about results. Can I make this all stay the way I want it? Is there a command where I can put empty spaces that don't show up on page to fill that gap? I just can't use `\\` repeatedly since my LaTeX program gives me an error that there is no line there to skip. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put `\clearpage` before the result section.

Comment: that sort of worked but now there is a blank page between the result section and where the table ends. how do get rid of the blank page

Comment: It should be `\end{sidewaystable}\clearpage <Your results>` Nothin more inbetween.

Comment: here is what I am doing but there is still a blank page between http://i65.tinypic.com/2889izr.jpg

Comment: look here http://i67.tinypic.com/j5immo.jpg

Comment: Bakhtawar, showing me images like this is asking a mechanic to fix the car just by showing him a picture of the car. Really helpful would be a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) that let's us reproduce your case. Are there any errors or warnings? What happens if you remove the last column of the table? I think the table might just be too big for one page.

Comment: i dont know how to use minimal working example :(... there are no errors though... =/ i tried resizing the table it got shorter but still the blank page exists.

Comment: That is why i linked to a site explaining in short what a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a MWE answering your question is like looking into a dirty crystal ball, so if this is not what you want, please send window cleaner...

> Code taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289036/36296

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in,head=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}% to remove the line
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=2cm]{example-image.png}}% use your logo
\rhead{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{5cm}
\flushright
\today\\
IND/Q-85/15 \\
Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}
\vspace{6mm}
\end{minipage}}
\cfoot{}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Forst chapter}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1]

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]

\afterpage{\clearpage}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{my biggggggggggggggggggggg table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
        this table is to wide to be fit in text width
    &   this table is to wide to be fit in text width
      &   this table is to wide to be fit in text width\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}

\lipsum[12-13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!! I LOVE YOU!!!!... i just used afterpage{clearpage} after all the tables I was using and it WORKED.. I LOVE YOU SO MUCH THANK YOU.. I WILL PERSONALLY CLEAN YOUR WINDOWS NOW xD